# Angular Drag Table Row To Dynamic Tab

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

`"@angular/cdk": "^16.2.5",     "@angular/material": "^16.2.6",`

Im making a component, that has multiple tabs (tabs can be created or deleted)
Each tab has a table (all tables are the same), and I want to create easy organising functionality, so for that I decided to use Angular DragDropModule. Im trying to drag 1 table row, and drop it to another tab, code would insert it inside that tab table.
But for some reason event container data is undefined.

Provided gif for clarity
[image: Idea]

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab
    *ngFor="let item of statements | async"
    cdkDropList
    (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
  >
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      {{ item.name }}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-container *ngIf="item.finances.length > 0; else noFinances">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Payer Info</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            *ngFor="let finance of item.finances"
            cdkDrag
            [cdkDragData]="{finance: finance, tabId: item.id}"
          >
            <td>{{ finance.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ finance.payerInfo }}</td>
            <td>{{ finance.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ finance.amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ finance.categoryId }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #noFinances>
      No finances available for this item.
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```